# Python websocket-client disconnecting when using AWS DynamoDB Streams

Tags: python, aws-lambda, websocket, amazon-dynamodb

I have a front end web app that allows users to push entries to a DynamoDB database on AWS.  I then have a python backend that has a websocket connection to AWS that is sent a message any time a new entry appears in the database.

I'm using the websocket-client module in python, and am basically just running their "Long-lived Connection" example which you can see on their git page https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client.

I had expected that using run_forever would  just keep the connection going and I would receive updates  as and when they occurred.. however after a short period of inactivity I get a going away message and the connection closes and no attempt is made to reconnect.

I've followed this guide:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/01/06/websockets-aws-dynamodb-updates/

for setting up the functionality at AWS.  This all works great, when the websocket connection is up and running.. i've tried looking through the docs on the websocket-client page but can't find anything useful.

I'm quite new to AWS and websockets.. I had thought using websockets would be a cheaper way to handle this problem rather than polling a database every second, do I need to manually handle the case that AWS disconnects and then reconnect again, or is there some option to increase the length of the time out?

I'm not really sure that the costs are of keeping the connection up longer either though.

If anyone can provide any advice/tips I would be happy to hear them!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a lot of overhead on your end. Why not use DynamoDB Streams and a Lambda trigger to consume the changes/insertions to your DynamoDB table? Its cost efficient and performant and you can even use Event Filters to only consume the items you want, no wasted compute.